# "PortMidi: `Bad pointer'" when closing mido port

Tags: python, pygame, midi, pyportmidi, mido

My code:

```
import mido
import time

mido.set_backend('mido.backends.pygame')

output = mido.open_output()
output.send(mido.Message('note_on', note=64, velocity=60))
time.sleep(3)
output.close()
```

After the last line, the following error is printed:

```
Exception Exception: "PortMidi: `Bad pointer'" in <pypm.Output object at 0x025FF0B0> ignored
```

Apart from that, everything seems to work fine. However I'm developing a console app and this output is annoying. How can I get rid of this error?

I am using Windows 7 and Python 2.7.

Comment: As always, present your [MCVE] for help with errors.

Comment: Try this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863534/playing-note-with-pygame-midi)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have added the code :)

Comment: If somebody's interested: I ended up just using the `RtMidi` backend. All is needed is `pip install python-rtmidi` and then `mido.set_backend('mido.backends.rtmidi')`. All works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to set the RtMidi backend as it is the default, see [mido backend documentation](http://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/rtmidi.html)